# How to make a loading screen for a website hold for a certain number of seconds

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm creating a website using the Salient theme in wordpress and I have a fairly large video file on the home page. So i set up a small gif to play as a loading image but sometimes the website loads too fast to even really see the gif.

Is there a piece of code that will force the website to hold of the loading screen for around 3-4 seconds by default?

http://www.ryanlrobinson.com is the website where you can see the issue for yourself

Comment: Your problem is that you (sometimes) don't need a loading screen but _want_ visitors to sit at one?

Comment: I am graphic design and the loading screen is more for visual effect than practicality

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you want is a `setTimeout`, but what you should do is preload the video.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    // Hide loading
}, 3000); // Time is in milliseconds
```

**Example**

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById("loading").style.display = 'none';
}, 3000);
```

```css
.video {
  width: 320px;
  height: 240px;
  position: relative;
}

#loading {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="video">
 <div id="loading">Loading...</div>
 
 <video width="320" height="240" autoplay>
  <source src="http://ryanlrobinson.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Home-Video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
 </video>
</div>
```

---

**Update** Based of comments.

Try this.

1. Go to **Plugins > Add new**.
2. Search for a plugin that allows you to add custom Javascript. For example, Custom JS.
3. Active the plugin.
4. Go to **Custom JS**
5. Copy & paste the following code in the **Add JS in Footer**.

---

```
var loading = document.createElement('div');
loading.className = 'loading';
document.getElementsByClassName('swiper-wrapper')[0].appendChild(loading);
setTimeout(function(){
    loading.style.display = 'none';
}, 3000);
```

---

6. Now go to **CSS/Script Releted** section and paste the following code on **Custom CSS Code**

---

```
.loading {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000 url('data:image/gif;base64,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') center center no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: just copy and paste this as it is? Because it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @RyanRobinson No, you need to do other things too. You have to create a loading div and show it in front of the video. Then, with the setTimeout you wait 3000 milliseconds (3 seconds) and hide the loading div. I updated the answer, look the example.

Comment: Is there anything in that example that i would have to change or add in myself? I should've mention in the original post that i know nothing about code.

Comment: Inside wordpress in the control panel for salient there is simply a box thats labelled custom css code and im just pasting it into their

Comment: @RyanRobinson Does this theme also have a "custom javascript code" section?

Comment: The section is called CSS/Script but i don't see anything thats specifically says Javascript

Comment: @RyanRobinson Screenshot?

Comment: @RyanRobinson Ok, see, you have HTML, Javascript and CSS in the place where you can only use CSS. You will need Javascript. I updated the answer. Check it.

Comment: @RyanRobinson Send me an email "agustinbarrientos [at] outlook dot com"

Comment: I can't get on outlook at the moment so i can't email you